# How do I see windows 8 files on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: windows

very new to ubuntu, and I think the interface is absolutely beautiful. I am using Ubuntu through the usb for now, after following this tutorial http://lifehacker.com/5504531/the-co...-a-thumb-drive - I have version 12.10 ubuntu.

1) My windows 8 imploded on me, it went from an automatic repair loop to constantly asking for repair and restarting itself. Sadly, none of the tools they provide have any effect, and this laptop is only a few weeks old. I booted ubuntu to try to get a file (literally one note document that I forgot to backup, and my exams are in a few days! Great timing ^ ^), the problem is I can only see some of the files under "Windows 8 OS --> Documents", I already have hidden items being shown, and tried CTRL+H. Other posts have said to CTRL+L host or /media/user, but neither of these work.

Thank you!

Comment: Mounting a **NTFS/Fat32 partition** in Ubuntu will result in corruption of the partition thus it will became **Unreadable** in Windows and you will have to reformat the partition.

Comment: @AlexandraO That isn't true. I've mounted my Windows partition many times and still Windows has been fine.

Answer (score 0):

from Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) home folder, choose *file system* (from the left panel menu), *host*, *Users*, *user's name*, *Documents*